# Set discount based on number of orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, discount

In WooCommerce, how to set discount based on number of order?

For example I would like to apply a discount based on customer orders:

- first order discount $50
- second order discount $30
- third order discount $10?

I've search internet but not found any solution or plugins available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** that will add to cart a custom discount based on customer orders count, this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'discount_based_on_customer_orders', 10, 1);
function discount_based_on_customer_orders( $cart_object ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;  

    // Getting "completed" customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );

    // Orders count
    $customer_orders_count = count($customer_orders);

    // The cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_total(); // or WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax()

    // First customer order
    if( empty($customer_orders) || $customer_orders_count == 0 ){
        $discount_text = __('First Order Discount', 'woocommerce');
        $discount = -50;
    } 
    // 2nd orders discount
    elseif( $customer_orders_count == 1 ){
        $discount_text = __('2nd Order Discount', 'woocommerce');
        $discount = -30;            
    } 
    // 3rd orders discount
    elseif( $customer_orders_count == 2 ){
        $discount_text = __('3rd Order Discount', 'woocommerce');   
        $discount = -10;        
    }

    // Apply discount
    if( ! empty( $discount ) ){
        // Note: Last argument is related to applying the tax (false by default)
        $cart_object->add_fee( $discount_text, $discount, false);
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> The only problem can be if customer is not logged in.
>
> You may add, at the beginning, in first condition `! is_user_logged_in()` this way:
>
> ```
>     if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
>         return;
> ```

Comment: hi do you know how to disable this if coupons are used?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is it possible to discount a percentage instead?