# Discount percentage from 1st & 4th order and apply to custom table

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using *"[Set discount based on number of orders in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084031/set-discount-based-on-number-of-orders-in-woocommerce/43085044#43085044)"* answer code making some changes to it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'discount_based_on_customer_orders', 10, 1);
function discount_based_on_customer_orders( $cart_object ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Getting "completed" customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );

    // Orders count
    $customer_orders_count = count($customer_orders);

    // The cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // First customer order
    if( empty($customer_orders) || $customer_orders_count == 0 ){
        $discount_text = __('First Order Discount', 'woocommerce');
        $discount = 0 - ($cart_total * 0.5);
    }
    // 4th order discount
    elseif( $customer_orders_count == 4 ){
        $discount_text = __('4th Order Discount', 'woocommerce');
        $discount = 0 - ($cart_total * 0.5);
    }

    // Apply discount
    if( ! empty( $discount ) ){
        // Note: Last argument is related to applying the tax (false by default)
        $cart_object->add_fee( $discount_text, $discount, false);
    }
}
```

I've set it to the first and fourth order for a customer and also a percentage instead of a fixed price.

I'd like to apply that to a custom checkout page using something like:

```
<?php
if($discount == true){
    ?>
    <tr class="table__row discount_row discountrow">
        <th class="table__cell table__cell--head  table__cell--item table__cell--regular" scope="row" data-title="Discount">Discount</th>
        <td class="table__cell table__cell--quantity" data-title="QTY"></td>
        <td class="table__cell table__cell--total table__cell--regular" data-title="Discount">&pound;<span class="referral_discount">-<?php echo number_format($discount,2);?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

How can that be done? So if the customer qualifies then it adds the correct lines to the checkout.

Comment: `$discount = 0 - ($cart_total * 0.5);`

Comment: @BrettGregson That doesn't seem to discount anything when I replace the current discount amounts.

Comment: `var_dump($cart_total); var_dump($discount); die();` what does that output?

Comment: @BrettGregson `string(118) "£0.00" int(-1)`. It doesn't seem to be taking the cart total and using it.

Comment: Your `$cart_total` is 0, so there is an issue with how you're getting it/calculating it. Once you've figured that out, this should work to calculate the discount as a value:

`$cart_total = floatval(str_replace("£", "", $cart_total)); $discount = 0 - ($cart_total * 0.5);`

Comment: @Rob In stackOverFlow you can only ask one question at the time, if you don't want your question to be closed as too broad.

Comment: @BrettGregson Thanks, got this working... I've updated the question with the first part. Just need to do the second part now.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I've answered the first part in the question, just the second part to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<?php
if( WC()->cart->get_fee_total() < 0 ){
    ?>
    <tr class="table__row discount_row discountrow">
        <th class="table__cell table__cell--head  table__cell--item table__cell--regular" scope="row" data-title="Discount">Discount</th>
        <td class="table__cell table__cell--quantity" data-title="QTY"></td>
        <td class="table__cell table__cell--total table__cell--regular" data-title="Discount">&pound;<span class="referral_discount">-<?php echo number_format($discount,2);?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Also `$discount = 0 - ($cart_total * 0.5);` can be replaced by `$discount = -$cart_total * 0.5;`